# How to crop a strip (width x height) in Blender VSE?

Tags: video, blender, editing, dimension

I have a several videos in a Blender project with dimension larger than 1280x720, which is my output dimension. Instead of rescaling my videos to fit the output dimension, I would like to crop them to 1280x720 pixels, so that part of the scene is discarded. This way, the remaining region would not seem distorted.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about using blender.

Comment: could be moved to the blender-specific site in the stack

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the VSE select the strip and show the properties sidebar <kbd>N</kbd>. There you will find a panel for Strip Input that has the crop settings.

[image]

Comment: Another useful thing to do is to enable "Image Offset" - as soon as I do that, scaling is disabled and the image is shown unsealed. It allows me to see how much larger the original video is.  And by using negative offsets, I can, for example, center the video and crop a bit on both sides.

Comment: @IlyaBobyr you may also like the addon I made for [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/107043/935) it adds several aligning options for multiple strips.